# Plaid bank Income verification doesn't trigger a webhook

Tags: plaid

I'm working in the integration with plaid and my node application.

I'm using this [guide](https://github.com/plaid/income-sample) and for some reason I'm not receiving any webhook when I finish the "bank income report process" through plaid widget.

So if I'm not receiving the event, how do I know when the bank income report is ready to be consumed? Is this behaviour correct?

Thanks in advance

If I use the same application / client and I test the "payroll income report process" through plaid widget. I receive a webhook like this one:

```
{
"environment": "sandbox",
"item_id": "DMVJD8yZr8SbPxGMJNGwu1e5PkMmo8fvyJVmP",
"user_id": "f18d7876a7387bd147a90283c6df64530b8392144a75c9f50209217c60d32e36",
"verification_status": "VERIFICATION_STATUS_PROCESSING_COMPLETE",
"webhook_code": "INCOME_VERIFICATION",
"webhook_type": "INCOME"
}
```

I'm expecting to receive a similar event when I finish the bank income report process

Comment: Have you verified that you can receive webhooks from Plaid at all? (For example, using the ` /sandbox/income/fire_webhook` to force an Income webhook to fire and then confirming that you've received it.) If not, you should make sure that that is working first.

Comment: yes, I can receive events from plaid. As I mentioned before if I use the "payroll income report" process I'm getting events but for some reason when I use "bank income report" process I'm not receiving anything

Answer (score 0):

Payroll Income / Document Income need to parse an image file containing document details before income data is ready. This can take a long time (potentially 30+ minutes), so these products send a webhook to indicate when the parsing is finished.

Because Bank Income connects directly to a user's bank account and does not need to extract data from an image file, income data is available almost immediately, so a webhook is not sent to indicate when data is available from Bank Income.

You should be able to call `/credit/bank_income/get` as soon as you have received the client-side `onSuccess` callback from Link. For more details, see the [Bank Income integration flow](https://plaid.com/docs/income/bank-income/#integration-process) in the Plaid documentation

Comment: Hi alex, 
I already read the documentation that you shared with me.


If you read the point 2, it says:

* Provide a webhook URI with the endpoint where you will receive Plaid webhooks.


That's why my confusion, right now we are using the sandbox environment and everything works fine and fast, but I'm not sure what is going to happens when we move to production, I mean I didn't read in any place stuff like: "you don't need to expect any event if you are using bank income verification"

Comment: Bank Income does not have specific success webhooks, but the webhook receiver endpoint is still needed to receive other webhooks that may occur when using Bank Income, such as Item error webhooks or new accounts available webhooks. https://plaid.com/docs/api/items/#webhooks